# How to remove property from Cheerio object?

Tags: node.js, cheerio

I need to get all element except first with `Cheerio`. So I select all and then try to delete first but after when I try to loop elements I get error that first element undefined...

```
var categories = $('.subtitle1');

console.log(categories.length);

delete categories[0];
delete categories['0'];

console.log(categories.length);

categories.each(function(i, element) {
    console.log(element.children);
});
```

Result:

```
15
15

TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined....
```

If I comment `delete...` everything works fine except that I have first element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this could solve your problem:

```
var $element = $(<htmlElement>);

$element = $element.slice(1); // Return all except first.
// $element = $element.slice(1, $element.length);
```

Documentation: https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#slice-start-end-

So in your case this should be work:

```
var categories = $('.subtitle1').slice(1);
categories.each(function(i, element) {
    console.log(element.children);
});
```